# How can I use a variable as a key in the associative array in autohotkey?

Tags: autohotkey

In autohotkey_L, there is a associative data structure. For example,

```
   hash := {key_hash:"value"}
   val:= hash["key_hash"]
   MsgBox %val%
```

But if I want to use a variable as a key to access the value in the assocative array, it fails. For example, the following doesn't work

```
  hash := {key_hash:"value"}
   other_val="key_hash"
   val:= hash[other_val]
   MsgBox %val%
```

and this doesn't work either:

```
   hash := {key_hash:"value"}
   other_val="key_hash"
   val:= hash[%other_val%]
   MsgBox %val%
   ** gave me an error: The following variable name contains an illegal character: ""key_hash""
```

How can I use a variable to access the value in an associative array?
I need this to get the key as an argument in a function.

Comment: Voted to close as too localized because the resolution was a common AutoHotkey typo, not reflected by the question title or body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alby,

Your variable other_val contained the data:  `"key_hash"`  , not what you wanted: `key_hash`. Just remove the two double quotes and you are fine.

```
hash := {key_hash:"value"}
other_val=key_hash
val:= hash[other_val]
MsgBox %val%
```

Answer (score 1):

Or use the assignment (:=)

```
hash:={key_hash:"value"} ; hash:=Object("key_hash", "value")
other_val:="key_hash"
val:=hash[other_val]
MsgBox, % val
```